# How do i figure out a total number of possible events based on percentages of occurrences?

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure out what are the average number a rolls it would take to earn a certian number of points.

The problem:

You have a 1350 points you can earn.

You are rolling two dice.

---

33% Chance for either die to land on 6.

3% chance for both to land on 6.

64% for any other combination.

---

No 6 = 1 point

Only one 6 = 5 points

Both 6s = 15 points

About how many rolls would it take to earn 1350 points?

I am not even sure how to set this up.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compute the expected score per roll.  You have $33\%$ chance of scoring $5$, so that contributes $0.33\cdot 5=1.65$ points per roll.  Add in the other two results and you get the total expected number of points per roll.  Divide into $1350$ and you are there.   It is not exact, but for a large number of rolls is rather close.

Comment: Do I add or average them?(1: 1)(5: 1.666666667)(15: 0.4166666667)
 TOTAL: 3.083333333

Comment: You add them as one or another will happen.  We are looking for the long term average number of points per roll.  I don't understand the numbers in your last comment, but the 5 looks like you divided by 3 to get 1.666666667.  The original question said the chance was $33\%$, not $\frac 13$, which is slightly different.  The probabilities you list are not correct for two standard dice, but if we believe them it doesn't matter where the events come from.  It is just $33\%$ to score $5$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    const int SIZE=1350+15; //also the maxinum of the points plus one
    double * possibility=new double[SIZE];
    double * average_steps=new double[SIZE];
    for(int i=1;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        possibility[i]=0.0;
        average_steps[i]=0.0;
    }
    possibility[0]=1.0;
    average_steps[0]=0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE-15;i++)
    {
        possibility[i+1]+=0.64 * possibility[i];
        average_steps[i+1]+=0.64 * (average_steps[i] + possibility[i]);
        possibility[i+5]+=0.33 * possibility[i];
        average_steps[i+5]+=0.33 * (average_steps[i] + possibility[i]);
        possibility[i+15]+=0.03 * possibility[i];
        average_steps[i+15]+=0.03 * (average_steps[i] + possibility[i]);
    }
    double sum=0.0;
    for(int i=SIZE-15;i<SIZE;i++)
        sum+=average_steps[i];
    cout<<sum;
    delete [] possibility;
    delete [] average_steps;
    return 0;
}`
I made this program in C++, and ran it, and the output is:
493.56
It will take a few steps to prove the program is correct. ( For convenience, I will use p[i] and a[i] instead of possibility[i] and average_steps[i], and s[i] refers to actual average steps cost to get to i points )
At the beginning of the program, all the elements of the two arrays are initialized to 0 except p[0] ( it is 1.0 ), which means I haven't rolled any dice yet.
Then during the second loop in the program, i increases from 0 to 1349. And when i=n, p[n] means the possibility of going through n points before I get to 1350 points. s[n] is the average number of steps when I get to n points, and a[n] = s[n] * p[n].

If p[n-15], p[n-5], p[n-1], a[n-15], a[n-5] and a[n-1] have been correctly calculated ( if they doesn't exist, think of them as correctly calculated ), p[n] and a[n] will be correctly calculated. That is because:
The possibility of going through a points equals the sum of all the possibility that goes into a point, so p[n] = 0.03*p[n-15] + 0.33*p[n-5] + 0.64*p[n-1].
The average number of steps equals weighted sum divided by total possibility, so s[n] = ((s[n-15]+1) * (p[n-15]*0.03) + (s[n-5]+1) * (p[n-5]*0.33) + (s[n-1]+1) * (p[n-1]*0.64)) / p[n], and a[n] = (a[n-15]+p[n-15])*0.03 + (a[n-5]+p[n-5])*0.33 + (a[n-1]+p[n-1])*0.64 ( remember that a[n] = s[n] × p[n] ).
Since p[0] and a[0] are correctly calculated, all 0~1364 elements are correctly calculated, then add the average steps from 1350 to 1364, and I get the answer.

Comment: A more accurate possibility of rolling two dice and only one of them is 5 is 28%. Do you really want the result calculated by using 33%?

Comment: I just assumed 1/6 + 1/6  = 1/3  I will go with 28%  Thanks for the C++ version of calculating this.